# Saving paired value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

For example:

```
An item
{
size:23"
Resolution:1920*1080
Panel:IPS
}
(as in an usual table)
```

The usual way one store in mysql would be making a column name 'size',etc. However, since the first item of the pair under my concern would be indefinite (say I would like user to be able to input data like producer:samsung; or whatever data pair that the user want to input)

Is there a way to do it elegantly in mysql? Maybe a common separated strings? In any case I would want these data to be easily output as table, and potential doing search like get all item with size=22" .

Comment: You want the [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model.

Comment: This sounds more like a 'nosql' situation. Either you have a set schema ("size", "model", etc) or you just have values. Avoid putting comma separated pairs into a sql column. It will make you sad.

Comment: please be more precise, a documented example will be appreciated , what I understand that you need to have multiple entries for the same column.

Comment: Hello ethrbunny I have also heard about not to put comma separated value in mysql field, but it seems to me some functions like explode() handle the task pretty well. What are the main difficulty actually with such approach?

Comment: @user1906418: Then put json into a textfield. The Mysql database at some point in time then might even support that.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL solution.

```
Entity    Key        Value
An item   size       23"
An item   Resolution 1920*1080
An item   Panel      IPS

SELECT * FROM table where Entity = 'An item'; //Selecting info on an item

SELECT * FROM table where Entity IN   //Selecting info on items with size = '22"'
   (SELECT Entity WHERE Key = 'size' AND Value = '22"');
```

Comments:

- All data is stored as strings, loss of DB typechecking and inefficient
- Lots of application logic and sub-queries.
- You could make entity an ID and have another table for the entity name and any required fields.
- It's a multi-field key table (Entity,Key)

Why this is the best approach:

- Comma separated values inside a single field break the whole point of databases.

This property is 1st Normal Form. If you put multiple values in a field you won't be able to sort on the field with SQL (at least not in a way that is reasonably quick).

You also have issues like parsing to contend with - more characters that must be escaped.

- Altering table schema and adding new fields at runtime is also bad for performance.

You will end up with very sparse tables, lots of NULL entries.

Comment: Thank a lot this is a very constructive answer. I am not sure if I read your sentence on "inefficient" correctly. Do you mean if I must do this in mysql this is the best way, but there are other framework that is more suitable and efficent for that?

Comment: Yes, basically. I believe NoSQL might have a better system but not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
table_name( primary_key, pair_name, pair_value)

select *
from table_name
where (pair_name = 'size' and pair_value = '22')
and primary_key = ........
```